# Set Range to Empty Space between Last Row and End of Print Area - Excel VBA PrintArea

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to add a bottom border to the last lines on a worksheet for notes. So it will print blank lines. I'm trying to figure out how to set the range to be the LastRow +1 to the End of the PrintArea on that page.

I found this function, but it just seems to return whatever I input as the range and I'm not sure it's doing what I want, any ideas?

```
Sub Test()
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:F10000"
Call PrintAreaLastRow
End Sub

Function PrintAreaLastRow() As Long
    With Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)
        PrintAreaLastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
        Debug.Print PrintAreaLastRow
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to expand the print area one below the last row?

Comment: What do you mean you want "put blank lines on the last page"? You don't need to add blank lines!

Comment: Yes you do! This is a blank line `_______`. This is blank space `"     " `

Comment: OK so you want to add cell borders? Or underscores.

Comment: "I'm looking to add a bottom border to the last lines" - possibly I'm being a bit slow ... But are you saying you don't want these lines printed?

Comment: Downvotter care to explain what needs to be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.hpagebreaks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hpagebreaks

Test:

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim lPrintRow As Integer
lPrintRow = LastPrintRow(ws)
Debug.Print lPrintRow

Dim UnUsedRng As Range
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lColLet = Split(Cells(1, lCol).Address, "$")(1)
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Set UnUsedRng = ws.Range("A" & lRow & ":" & lColLet & lPrintRow)

UnUsedRng.Borders(xlBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
UnUsedRng.Borders(xlBottom).Weight = xlThin

End Sub
```

Func:

```
Public Function LastPrintRow(ByRef strSheet As Worksheet) As Integer

Dim RowsPerPage As Long, PrintPages As Long
pgBreak = strSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location.Address(False, False)
RowsPerPage = Right(pgBreak, Len(pgBreak) - 1) - 1
PrintPages = strSheet.HPageBreaks.Count + 1
LastPrintRow = RowsPerPage * PrintPages - PrintPages + 1
Debug.Print LastPrintRow

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim rngBlankLines As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:F10000"
    
    With ws.Range(ws.PageSetup.PrintArea)
       Set rngBlankLines = ws.Range(ws.Cells(GetPrintAreaLastUsedRow(ws) + 1, .Cells(1, 1).Column), _
                                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
    End With
    
    With rngBlankLines
        ' Select to check if it is the range you expect (Delete if correct)
        .Select
        
'        ' Add your formatting below (uncomment if rngBlankLines is the correct range)
'        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
'            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
'            .Weight = xlThin
'        End With
'
'        With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
'            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
'            .Weight = xlThin
'        End With
'
'        ' Perhaps give more room for hand-writing
'        .EntireRow.RowHeight = .Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.RowHeight * 1.5
    End With
    
End Sub

Function GetPrintAreaLastUsedRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim i As Long, lTemp As Long
    
    If ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = "" Then Exit Function
    
    With ws.Range(ws.PageSetup.PrintArea)
        For i = 1 To .Columns.Count
            lTemp = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            If GetPrintAreaLastUsedRow < lTemp Then GetPrintAreaLastUsedRow = lTemp
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Only thing I'm concerned about is setting the print area, how do I do that? I basically want to print everything with some extra blank lines on last page.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this but it looks a lot cleaner then my answer, I'm just surprised you don't use 'HPageBreaks' at all