# Working with PageBreaks in Excel Javascript API

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I'm trying to figure out PageBreaks in Excel w/ the Javascript API.

My goal is to put blank lines on the end of the last page, filling up the unknown amount of blank space.

I've been reading the docs on PageBreaks and noticed a funciton `getCellAfterBreak()` which seems like a good starting point. I'd need to get the offset range of the cell above that to the bottom of my `UsedRange`.

I can't really seem to get any useful information from the console or docs, here is what I've been trying, can anybody point me how to use these funcitons?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pagebreak?view=excel-js-preview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.pagebreak?view=office-scripts

Code:

```
var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
var PageBKs = ws.horizontalPageBreaks
PageBKs.load('items')
await context.sync()
console.log('PageBKs')
console.log(PageBKs)
var Count = PageBKs.getCount()
console.log('Count')
console.log(Count)
```

Comment: The worksheet.horizontalPageBreaks and worksheet.verticalPageBreaks collection properties only return the page breaks that have been added manually to the worksheet. That might be why you are not getting anything useful with the code above. I am trying to figure, if there is a way to also get the automatic page breaks using the Excel JS API.

Comment: @JakobNielsen-MSFT FYI, here is my VBA based Q/A --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63419182/set-range-to-empty-space-between-last-row-and-end-of-print-area-excel-vba-prin

Comment: I may just look at default # of Rows/Page and make something ruff

Comment: @JakobNielsen-MSFT Can you show how to work w/ `PageBreaks` "normally" to help me diagnose?

Comment: There is a sample in Script Lab called "Page layout and print settings". It shows how to add page breaks. Try extending that sample with function to list the page breaks.